# Aren't beans referenced with "ref" guaranteed to be initialized before their dependent?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am reading on Spring Framework "depends-on" in Chapter 7, and I came across the following:

> The depends-on attribute can explicitly force one or more beans to be initialized before the bean using this element is initialized.

Aren't beans (dependencies) referenced with "ref" guaranteed to be initialized before the dependent (just as "depends-on")? If not, then can you give me an example and its use case?

Answer (score 0):

`DependsOn` (or the XML equivalent `depends-on`) is *only* used when there is no *explicit* dependency through constructor/property injection (e.g. `ref`), but you still want to make sure some bean is created before some other bean.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html):

> Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. **Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments**, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.

Comment: I guess it's appropriate when you don't need a reference to a dependency but only its side effect (loading the DB driver in a static initializer block). But the order of loading is still the same, that is the container initializes the dependencies first then the dependent. right?